# Can I create a custom DialogPreference based on a pre-existing custom Dialog?

Tags: android-layout, sharedpreferences, android, android-dialog

In my Android project I've already created a custom dialog: A class named `SelectColorDialog`, extending `Dialog`, that allows the user to view a large matrix of color cells in order to select a particular color.  The dialog returns the selected color value (as `Integer`) to the dialog initiator – typically an Activity – via a callback function.

I've a similar custom dialog, `SelectTypefaceDialog`, to allow easy font selection. A list of available typefaces are shown, as `ListView` rows, each identified by name and with an associated short sample text rendered in that typeface. The available typefaces include usual droid fonts, such as NORMAL,  MONOSPACE, etc. as well as any externally sourced TTF font files that the user cares to load into a particular subdirectory on the SDCard.

These custom dialogs were not initially designed to be used directly in conjunction with SharedPreferences, preferences definition XML files  or with any PreferenceActivity.  Instead of, each dialog can be popped up from any activity, via the user pressing a button or via a menu item.  The activity classes that create these dialogs also have internal callback classes, selection event listeners, to detect when the user selects a color or font.

These two dialogs do not have OK and Cancel buttons.  Instead, the user just clicks on an item - a view of some kind - in the dialog to select the corresponding color or typeface value (implicit OK) or else presses the device’s back button to dismiss the dialog with no action taken (implicit Cancel).

I would now like to go further and incorporate these two custom dialogs into the shared preferences framework via a `preferences.XML` and an associated `PreferenceActivity`.

I would prefer to base two `DialogPreference` subclasses directly on these existing dialogs if possible, but I cannot see how to do so.  I suspect that I cannot, and that I'll need to start all over again, and copy or adapt all the java code that is presently in the custom dialog classes – for color or font display and selection – directly into the custom `DialogPreference` classes instead, perhaps by overriding `onCreateDialogView()` and/or other methods?

Answer (score 1):

This question may be a bit old, but I hope to help those, looking at the same problem in future: just extend Preference instead of DialogPreference. DialogPreference is designed badly and expected "official" way to use custom Dialog - overriding protected showDialog method does not work, because this single method contains half of class logic.